# SQL SERVER 2014 - SELECT INTO, ORDER BY - automatic clustered index?

Tags: sql-server

When I create a table using `SELECT INTO A`, and it has `ORDER BY x`, does SQL server automatically make x the primary key of `A` (thus auto create a clustered index)?

Comment: SQL Server does not make any assumptions in this case about what you want to use as a clustered index, and it couldn't possibly know where your primary key should be on the new table.

Comment: Thanks - I thought the `ORDER BY` would refer to the output data set, as this would be the case if I left out the `INTO`, correct?

Comment: `ORDER BY` only tells SQL Server how to `SELECT`, it has no impact on `INSERT` (see [comments here to confirm](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/681154/records-not-sorted-in-the-table-when-using-order-by-clause-to-insert-data-into-temp-table)). And even if it did, SQL Server isn't going to jump to the conclusion that your `SELECT` should dictate how you want your clustered index configured on the new table - *you* think about it that way, in this specific case, but SQL Server can't.

Comment: There have been plenty of requests for enhancements to `SELECT INTO`, such as [supporting indexes](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=490142), [specifying a clustered index](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/254716/clustered-index-on-select-into), and [targeting a specific filegroup](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=254140). Mostly met with crickets (though those items are worth reading over, especially comments from Microsoft). Creating the table first, as suggested below, gives you most control.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the `ORDER BY` applies to the `SELECT` query and not to the table created by `SELECT INTO`.
Using `ORDER BY` is unnecessary in this statement, because it doesn't even guarantee the rows are inserted into the new table in that order.
See [INTO Clause (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx)

Comment: Thanks - so I should just create a clustered index as a second step?

Comment: Yes; you'd probably want to create the index after table creation and insert, anyway - otherwise your insert would be very slow.

Comment: @dashnick, create the table and clustered index first, then insert the data. This minimizes potentially problematic locking issues, but most of all, the data is only sorted once.

Comment: And use TABLOCK on the insert - this can have a dramatic impact on the amount of time the initial insert takes.

Comment: @DanielHutmacher Can you explain why creating the index should be done before inserting, and what the locking issues are? (or point me to an article). I'm still learning index particulars.

Comment: `SELECT ... INTO` creates the table and populates it in a single atomic transaction. As such, the table schema is locked until the insert completes, which may take a while. Locking the schema can potentially lock the schema DMVs of the entire database for the duration. As for creating the index first: if the table (and clustered index) already exists, the data is sorted once when you run the `INSERT`. If not, the data is first stored on `INSERT`, then re-sorted when you add the clustered index, which consumes twice the I/O.